# Bind a non-fixed variable in SQL statement in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, cx-oracle

I would like to bind a variable that does not contain a fixed value into the SQL statement in python:

Example:

```py
import cx_Oracle
def(var1, var2):
....
  chkdate = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
  #some lines of code
  def db_select_query(conn_data,query,column_names):
    conn_str = 'some user defined data'
    conn = cx_Oracle.conn(conn_str)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(query, chkdate)
  #some lines of code
  query = """Select * from Table_A where date > :chkdate"""
```

But this doesn't seem to work. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Why are you calling `query` *after* `cur.execute`? Please advise on DB-API (i.e., pyodbc, psycopg2, pymysql) as this depends on how to run named parameters.

Comment: @Parfait , The query is defined within a function, which I'm calling later, It works fine when I pass in a hardcoded value, but I want it to accept any variable like mentioned in the question..Is it possible?

Comment: I do not understand your example. I still ask my original question. But read docs on how to [bind named parameters](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html) with `cxOracle`.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the cx_Oracle binding [doc](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html), as mentioned in the comments.

If you are binding a date as a string, you will need to match the default date format that your Oracle installation is using.  Instead, you could just bind the date directly.  Try something like:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    chkdate = datetime.datetime.now()
    sql = """select last_name, hire_date from employees where hire_date + (365*13) > :d"""
    for r in cursor.execute(sql, [chkdate]):
        print(r)
```

The data arithmetic is just because the sample EMPLOYEES tables were created some years ago and I wanted to match only a few rows.